# Scrapy Crawler has me stumped

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a written a few scrapy crawlers. This one has me stumped.
I'm scraping a faucet comapany's site. The layout is pretty simple. List page. Thumbnails on the list page take you to detail page. I get a bunch of info to be downloaded for every line item. I'm struggling to get the URL for the next page. I have done is a few times. The issue I'm running into is that my crawler isnt able to find the attribute href on a hyperlink marked by the a tag. It is able to find other attributes like "data-bind" but not href which is right there. Looks pretty straight forward & hence frustrating me all the more.

In the code below the crawler is printing the amazon list as:

```
[<Selector xpath='//div[@id="product-list"]//div[@id="displayedProducts"]//div[@data-bind="attr: { id: \'prd\' + ModelName().replace(\'-\', \'\'), \'data-sortorder\': SortOrder, \'class\': \'product \' + ModelName().replace(\'-\', \'\') }"]//div[@class="finishes"]//div[@data-bind="attr: { \'class\': \'finishSwatch \' + FacetCode() }"]' data=u'<div data-bind="attr: { \'class\': \'finish'>]
```

and Pages as []

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from homedepot.items import LowesItem
from homedepot.items import SwatchcolorItem

class SattySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "satty-pfister"
    allowed_domains = ["pfisterfaucets.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.pfisterfaucets.com/kitchen/category/kitchen-faucets"
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='pfisterfaucets\.com/[A-Z][a-zA-Z_/]+$'),
            'parse_category', follow=True,
        ),
    )


    def parse(self, response):
        print 'enterrrrrrrrrrrrr'
        #amazonlist = response.xpath('//ul[@id="products"]//li[@class="grid_3 "]//div//a[@class="preview_image js_product-link"]')
        amazonlist = response.xpath('//div[@id="product-list"]//div[@id="displayedProducts"]//div[@data-bind="attr: { id: \'prd\' + ModelName().replace(\'-\', \'\'), \'data-sortorder\': SortOrder, \'class\': \'product \' + ModelName().replace(\'-\', \'\') }"]//div[@class="finishes"]//div[@data-bind="attr: { \'class\': \'finishSwatch \' + FacetCode() }"]')

        print amazonlist
        pages = amazonlist.xpath('.//a//@href').extract()
        print 'pages'
        print pages
        #imglarges = amazonlist.xpath('.//@srcset').extract()
        imgs = amazonlist.xpath('.//img//@src').extract()

    for idx1,page in enumerate(pages):

        print page
        url_next = response.urljoin(pages[idx1])
        print url_next 
        yield scrapy.Request(url_next,callback=self.parse_productdetail)            

        for next_url in response.xpath('//div[@class="float-right pagination-pages"]//div//a'):

            urls= next_url.xpath('.//@href').extract()
            for idx1,url in enumerate(urls):
                url_next = response.urljoin(urls[idx1])
                print url_next
                yield scrapy.Request(url_next, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_productdetail(self, response):
        tits='blank'
        #<div class="tabs-navigation group long">
        #//div[contains(@class, "tabs-navigation")]
        for imgs in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "tabs-navigation")]//ul[@class="tabs"]//li//img') :

               imgurl= imgs.xpath('.//@href').extract()
               name = imgs.xpath('.//@alt').extract()
               print 'imggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg'
               print imgurl 
               lowesitem = LowesItem(prod=name, file_urls=[imgurl])
               yield lowesitem
```

Comment: because there is AJAX items loading / scrapy doesn't execute js ... but anyway it's pretty easy to get them using plain requests (not xpath) -  look through XHR requests in your browser network panel

Comment: Thanks for the tip madzohan. Could you point me to any tutorial in scrapy using XHR to get me started . Never dealt with XHR requests or if you could  suggest code changes to get me started, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: http://toddhayton.com/2015/03/11/scraping-ajax-pages-with-python/